how to modify the number of submission queue or completion queue on nvme ssd
My NVMe SSD is WD_BLACK AN1500 :

when I do this command in my machine

dmesg |grep nvme0

I got :
enter image description here
I kown that my ssd default queue number is 3 ;

when I do :

sudo nvme id-strl /dev/nvme0 -H

I got :
enter image description here
I know that my ssd max SQ number is 64 and max CQ number is 16 ;

My question is how to modify the SQ/CQ number in my ssd ,so that I can use as many queues I want to achive maximize utilization of SSD.

Thanks !

I have tried the set-feature command , but have no effect on queue number modification.
for example :

sudo nvme set-feature /dev/nvme0 -f 7 -v 0x000f000f

